# How to populate devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to populate db with fake data, using faker and populator gems.
Using Devise generated a model User.

this is my rake file

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    [User, Article].each(&:delete_all)
    password = "password"

    User.populate 20 do |user|
      user.name = Faker::Name.name
      user.email = Faker::Internet.email
      user.password = password
      user.password_confirmation = password
      Article.populate 5 do |article|
        article.user_id = user.id
        article.title = Populator.words(1..3).titleize
        article.content = Populator.sentences(2..10)
        article.created_at = 2.years.ago..Time.now
      end
    end

  end
end
```

When i run rake db:populate raises the following

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `password=' for #<Populator::Record:0xa179d14>
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/populator-1.0.0/lib/populator/record.rb:64:in `method_missing'
    /home/sunloverz/RubymineProjects/socialnews/lib/tasks/sample_date.rake:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/populator-1.0.0/lib/populator/factory.rb:53:in `call'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/populator-1.0.0/lib/populator/factory.rb:53:in `block in build_records'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/populator-1.0.0/lib/populator/factory.rb:50:in `times'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/populator-1.0.0/lib/populator/factory.rb:50:in `build_records'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/populator-1.0.0/lib/populator/factory.rb:43:in `block in populate'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/populator-1.0.0/lib/populator/factory.rb:29:in `remember_depth'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/populator-1.0.0/lib/populator/factory.rb:42:in `populate'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/populator-1.0.0/lib/populator/model_additions.rb:25:in `populate'
    /home/sunloverz/RubymineProjects/socialnews/lib/tasks/sample_date.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
    Tasks: TOP => db:populate
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Try deleting `password = "password"` and just use `user.password = "password"` `user.password_confirmation = "password"`.

Comment: I have the same problem, though `user.password = password` works in the console !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Populator doesn't load the ActiveRecord instance; so any validations, callbacks, embedded methods wouldn't work. Instead it loads its own [Record](http://populator.rubyforge.org/classes/Populator/Record.html) object, using columns attributes and pure SQL to boost performance.

On the other hand, Devise doesn't create :password column, it creates encrypted_password column and does all the logic behind the scene, check this [link](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#valid_password?-instance_method) if you want to have insight about devise code.

Solution: We need to call password_digest to encrypt the given password, and then set the encrypted_password directly, but this [method](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#password_digest-instance_method) is protected and can't be called inside the rake. Instead we would use the 'new' method to trigger password_digest, so your code would be something like this:

```
password = "password"

User.populate 20 do |user|
  user.name = Faker::Name.name
  user.email = Faker::Internet.email
  user.encrypted_password = User.new(:password => password).encrypted_password
  # rest of your code here      
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was using my own session/cookie based auth using `password_digest`, so for anyone doing that, first set `password = "password"` like above, then for setting it, use `user.password_digest = User.new(:password => password).password_digest`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Model (table in your case) `actually` has a column named `"password"`.

If so, then, try to check if it has `attr_accessible :password`

Comment: It has a column password and attr_accessible :password in User model